# Converting Javascript DOM element to React

Tags: reactjs

I'm practicing using React.js and want to try converting a cool javascript canvas animation I found online into a reusable component. I've found the code below which turns a `<canvas>` into a trippy line animation platform. Prepare to have your mind blown:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var TAU = 2 * Math.PI;

times = [];
function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  update();
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function Ball (startX, startY, startVelX, startVelY) {
  this.x = startX || Math.random() * canvas.width;
  this.y = startY || Math.random() * canvas.height;
  this.vel = {
    x: startVelX || Math.random() * 2 - 1,
    y: startVelY || Math.random() * 2 - 1
  };
  this.update = function(canvas) {
    if (this.x > canvas.width + 50 || this.x < -50) {
      this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
    }
    if (this.y > canvas.height + 50 || this.y < -50) {
      this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
    }
    this.x += this.vel.x;
    this.y += this.vel.y;
  };
  this.draw = function(ctx, can) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = .4;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#448fda';
    ctx.arc((0.5 + this.x) | 0, (0.5 + this.y) | 0, 3, 0, TAU, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

var balls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.width * canvas.height / (65*65); i++) {
  balls.push(new Ball(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height));
}

var lastTime = Date.now();
function update() {
  var diff = Date.now() - lastTime;
  for (var frame = 0; frame * 16.6667 < diff; frame++) {
    for (var index = 0; index < balls.length; index++) {
      balls[index].update(canvas);
    }
  }
  lastTime = Date.now();
}
var mouseX = -1e9, mouseY = -1e9;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
});

function distMouse(ball) {
  return Math.hypot(ball.x - mouseX, ball.y - mouseY);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.globalAlpha=1;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#001c33';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var index = 0; index < balls.length; index++) {
    var ball = balls[index];
    ball.draw(ctx, canvas);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var index2 = balls.length - 1; index2 > index; index2 += -1) {
      var ball2 = balls[index2];
      var dist = Math.hypot(ball.x - ball2.x, ball.y - ball2.y);
        if (dist < 100) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#448fda";
          ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (dist > 100 ? .8 : dist / 150);
          ctx.lineWidth = "2px";
          ctx.moveTo((0.5 + ball.x) | 0, (0.5 + ball.y) | 0);
          ctx.lineTo((0.5 + ball2.x) | 0, (0.5 + ball2.y) | 0);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

// Start
loop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

All you React experts out there: If you were to try make this into a reusable component, where would be the best place to define the canvas's behavior? Should I put it all in the `componentDidMount()`? If so, should I reference the actual canvas by initializing the canvas in the `render()` with a `ref={(el) => this.canvas = el;}`?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check out how these projects were done?  https://react.rocks/tag/Canvas

Answer (score 0):

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/firice/pen/vJojmP) is a quick and dirty React conversion from your functions to `Canvas` component. I make it with the capability of managing its id itself. The rest depends on your design and logical, you can make every property from `props` or `state`. As you say, everything should go under `componentDidMount`. And of course you can update this `Canvas` component using `ref`.